# ROS Answers SE migration: IPv6 Support

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I just wanted to ask the community if there are any plans to make ROS support the IPv6 stack? I think it would make certain setups much easier.

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1322732482.079127983]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1322732482.079207093]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1322732482.079243271]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [XXXX.ipv6.XXXX.com]
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [XXXX.ipv6.XXXX.com]

$ rostopic list
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

$ ping6 XXXX.ipv6.XXXX.com
PING XXXX.ipv6.XXXX.com(2a01:xxx:xxx:xx::x) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:xxx:xxx:xx::x icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=32.0 ms
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12171/ipv6-support/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS currently doesn't support IPv6 but we'd be happy to accept patches to provide this compatibility.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-12-01**:
Perhaps I'll have a look at it over Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first working beta implementation of Ros using IPv6 stack is now on the way.
See http://www.ros.org/news/2012/06/ipv6-support-for-ros-nodes.html for details.

Should be pushed back in a few months in the regular stack.

---

Originally posted by [roalter](https://answers.ros.org/users/667/roalter/) with karma: 41 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4